# Problems adding phpMyAdmin to my LEMP stack using docker

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, phpmyadmin

I am trying to add phpMyAdmin to my LEMP stack using docker and i cant get it to work,

I use nginx-proxy in another container and thats why i specify VIRTUAL_HOST and only exposes port 80
and the main-page works as it should.

I only get File not Found error and i have tested with a bunch of different configurations but nothing works and i am not very good with NGINX configurations.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
php:
    build:
        context: ./docker
        dockerfile: php.Dockerfile
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}-php
    networks:
        - backend
    volumes:
        - './app:/var/www/html'
        - 'phpmyadmin_data:/var/www/html/phpmyadmin:ro'
    depends_on:
        - mariadb

nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}-nginx
    networks:
        - frontend
        - backend
    expose:
        - 80
        - 443
    environment:
        VIRTUAL_HOST: ${VIRTUAL_HOST}
    links:
        - 'php'
        - 'phpmyadmin'
    volumes:
        - './app:/var/www/html:ro'
        - 'phpmyadmin_data:/var/www/html/phpmyadmin:ro'
        - './config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro'
    depends_on:
        - php

mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.3.9
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}-mariadb
    restart: 'on-failure'
    networks:
        - backend
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
        - ${PWD}
phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:fpm-alpine
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}-phpmyadmin
    networks:
        - backend
    volumes:
        - 'phpmyadmin_data:/var/www/html'
    environment:
        PMA_HOST: mariadb
    depends_on:
        - mariadb

 volumes:
     phpmyadmin_data:

 networks:
     frontend:
         external:
             name: 'frontend'
     backend: {}
```

And here is my nginx.conf:

```
server {
index index.php index.html;
server_name localhost;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
root /var/www/html;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$query_string;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}

location /phpmyadmin {
    fastcgi_pass phpmyadmin:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}
}
```